# Can a variable be produced from an if else statement?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can I change a variables value based on an if/else statement in javascript?

```js
var $nextLink = $this.next().attr('href'),
 $currentLink = $this.attr('href');

if ($currentLink == $nextLink){              // Check if next link is same as current link
  var $nextLoad = $this.eq(2).attr('href');  // If so, get the next link after the next
}
else {var $nextLoad = $nextLink;}
```

Comment: can, but youre better off settng it outside to what you have in the else and then just not having an else.

Comment: There's no need to use `$` to denote variables, FYI. That's a PHP thing, not a JavaScript thing. The exception being a common convention where variables containing jQuery objects are decorated with a leading `$`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code shown in the question will work. Note, though, that JavaScript doesn't have block scope, only function scope. That is, variables declared inside an `if` or `else` statement's `{}` block (or a `for` statement's `{}`, etc.) will be visible in the surrounding function. In your case I think that's actually what you intend, but still most JS coders would probably find it neater to declare the variable before the if/else and then just set its value with the if/else.

Neater still is to do it in one line using the [`?:` conditional (or ternary) operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator):

```
var $nextLoad = $currentLink == $nextLink ? $this.eq(2).attr('href') : $nextLink;
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, though take care for JavaScript's variable hoisting and function scope (the {} code blocks for your if statement are not variable scopes).

To clarify, your code is equivalent to:

```
var $nextLink = $this.next().attr('href'),
 $currentLink = $this.attr('href'),
 $nextLoad;

if ($currentLink == $nextLink){              // Check if next link is same as current link
  $nextLoad = $this.eq(2).attr('href');  // If so, get the next link after the next
}
else {$nextLoad = $nextLink;}
```

Comment: this is bad practice though. other programming languages won't allow this

Comment: @SomeshMukherjee That's why we have practices for each pregramming language.

Comment: @SomeshMukherjee - What exactly is the bad practice that other languages don't allow?

Comment: if you declare a variable inside a conditional/loop scope, you can't access it outside. javascript will allow you, but java or C++ won't.

Comment: @SomeshMukherjee - JavaScript doesn't let you access variables from outside "a scope" either, the point is that in JS `{}` doesn't create scope; it has no "conditional/loop scope". In any case really you are commenting on the code in the question, not the code in this answer (which already covered your point).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do that, but javascript doesn't have block scope, so any var declarations get hoisted up to the function level, for example:

```
function foo() {
    var x = 1;
    if (x === 1) {
        var y = 2;
    }
    console.log(y); // Can see y here, it's local to the fn, not the block
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, but [jslint, The JavaScript Code Quality Tool,](http://jslint.com) will ask you to move all `var my_var;` into one place...